# Cannot access asset in spring-boot project due to spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, resources, thymeleaf

I am facing quite an interesting issue. In my `controller` class I added path `@RequestMapping("/product")`. Inside class when I put a path on method like `@GetMapping("/update/{productId}")` that means when I divided path by `/` I cannot access asset file in my `html` page. But if I define path like `@GetMapping("/{productId}")` it works fine. Using path like `@GetMapping("/update/{productId}")` this my asset URL become like this.

```
 http://localhost:8080/product/assets/js/editor/ckeditor/ckeditor.custom.js
```

You can see `/product/` added automatically in the URL. As a result, html page cannot find those assets as there is no `product` folder and get `404`

And using a path like `@GetMapping("/{productId}")` asset url become fine

```
http://localhost:8080/assets/js/editor/ckeditor/ckeditor.custom.js
```

My `controller` class is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class AdminProductController {

@GetMapping("/update/{productId}")
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("admin/add-product");
        //my code
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

In my `WebSecurityConfig` i configured like bellow.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/admin/login","/customer/login", "/logout","/file/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**","/category/**","/product/*").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/customer/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_CUSTOMER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .loginPage("/customer/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureUrl("/customer/login?error")
                .successHandler(successHandler);
        http
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll();
    }


    @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/assets/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
        }
```

and I also added this code in `WbMvcConfifure`

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:META-INF/resources/static/");
    }
```

and here is my `add-product.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description"
 content="Bigdeal admin is super flexible, powerful, clean &amp; modern responsive bootstrap 4 admin template with unlimited possibilities.">
<meta name="keywords"
 content="admin template, Bigdeal admin template, dashboard template, flat admin template, responsive admin template, web app">
<meta name="author" content="pixelstrap">
<link rel="icon" href="../assets/images/favicon/favicon.ico"
 type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/images/favicon/favicon.ico"
 type="image/x-icon">
<title>P&S Craft- Hand made,Hand print & Natural</title>

<!-- Google font-->
<link
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900"
 rel="stylesheet">
<link
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
 rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Font Awesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 th:href="@{/assets/css/font-awesome.css}">

<!-- Flag icon-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="@{/assets/css/flag-icon.css}">

<!-- Bootstrap css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 th:href="@{/assets/css/bootstrap.css}">

<!-- App css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/assets/css/admin.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dropify/0.2.2/css/dropify.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.css" />

</head>
<body>

 <!-- page-wrapper Start-->
 <div class="page-wrapper">

  <!-- Page Header Start-->
  <div th:replace="fragments/header_admin :: header"></div>
  <!-- Page Header Ends -->

  <!-- Page Body Start-->
  <div class="page-body-wrapper">

   <!-- Page Sidebar Start-->
   <div th:replace="fragments/leftsidebar_admin :: leftsidebar"></div>
   <!-- Page Sidebar Ends-->

   <!-- Right sidebar Start-->
   <div th:replace="fragments/rightsidebar_admin :: rightsidebar"></div>
   <!-- Right sidebar Ends-->

   <div class="page-body">

    <!-- Container-fluid starts-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="page-header">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="page-header-left">
         <h3>
          Add Products 
         </h3>
        </div>
       </div>
      
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Container-fluid Ends-->

    <!-- Container-fluid starts-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
     
    </div>
    <!-- Container-fluid Ends-->

   </div>

   <!-- footer start-->
   <div th:replace="fragments/footer_admin :: footer"></div>
   <!-- footer end-->

  </div>

 </div>

 <!-- latest jquery-->
 <script src="../assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Bootstrap js-->
 <script src="../assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

 <!-- feather icon js-->
 <script src="../assets/js/icons/feather-icon/feather.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../assets/js/icons/feather-icon/feather-icon.js"></script>

 <!-- Sidebar jquery-->
 <script src="../assets/js/sidebar-menu.js"></script>

 <!-- touchspin js-->
 <script src="../assets/js/touchspin/vendors.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../assets/js/touchspin/touchspin.js"></script>
 <script src="../assets/js/touchspin/input-groups.min.js"></script>

 <!-- form validation js-->
 <script src="../assets/js/dashboard/form-validation-custom.js"></script>

 <!-- ckeditor js-->
 <script src="../assets/js/editor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script src="../assets/js/editor/ckeditor/styles.js"></script>
 <script src="../assets/js/editor/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="../assets/js/editor/ckeditor/ckeditor.custom.js"></script>

 <!-- Zoom js-->
 <script src="../assets/js/jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script>
 <script src="../assets/js/zoom-scripts.js"></script>

 <!--Customizer admin-->
 <script src="../assets/js/admin-customizer.js"></script>

 <!-- lazyload js-->
 <script src="../assets/js/lazysizes.min.js"></script>

 <!--right sidebar js-->
 <script src="../assets/js/chat-menu.js"></script>

 <!--script admin-->
 <script src="../assets/js/admin-script.js"></script>
 

</body>

</html>
```

and here is my folder structure

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you include the contents of your `admin/add-product` view?

Comment: I have included it now. will you check again please? @ck1

Answer (score 0):

All the assets have to be linked using the approach:

```
th:href="@{/assets/css/<your css file name here>}"
```

Same with JS and any other static resources placed under `src/main/resources/static`

Comment: Why is this resource location registred `registry.addResourceHandler`? By default SpringBoot looks for resources in classpath under `static` folder

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I was facing the same problem before adding it. I have added it after seeing some answers in the stack overflow.

Comment: If you are using SpringBoot and embedded tomcat then you dont need to configure any resource handler. Just let Springboot manage it. And you place the static reosurces under `src/main/resources/static`

Comment: According to your suggestion, I have removed resource handler. And all of my resources are already under `src/main/resources/static`. I have attached my folder structure. But the problem still remains.

Comment: Can you add `.antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()` in your  `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method? Also try to open the resource directly using `localhost:8080/assets/css/flag-icon.css`, what do you see?

Comment: If i hit manually in this `http://localhost:8080/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` it returns code. but from page it become` http://localhost:8080/product/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` and I dont know how `product/` is appending infront of the `/assets`. if I make my root url long then that appends too like` http://localhost:8080/product/long-url/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`

Comment: It is because the resource lookup is not absolute. Did u try to use the approach I mentioned in the answer? If yes, then please update the HTML in your question. I can have a look

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla Check updated question. In html asset file are defined as you mentioned. But no result!

Comment: I said `th:href` and not `href`. Because `th:href` can understand `@{}` but not `href`

Comment: u are using it for few only. All you static JS and CSS should be configured that way.